# One of the unicode characters in my display name disappears in the Stack Exchange Android application

Tags: bug, android-app, display-names, unicode

So a few days I ago I thought I would make my display name slightly more unique by changing the last three characters to Latin Letter Small Capitals:

**C** - `U+0043`: Latin Capital Letter C

**ᴏ** - `U+1D0F`: Latin Letter Small Capital O

**ʀ** - `U+0280`: Latin Letter Small Capital R

**ʏ** - `U+028F`: Latin Letter Small Capital Y

Surely the change is completely pointless.

That said, I seem to have confused the Android application for Stack Exchange. Here's a screenshot from my LG G3:

[image: screen shot]

The darn O is missing!

I would hope that I can keep my cosmetic name change and not have to be known as  "Cry" :). Is this is a bug, or have I picked a non-standard Latin Letter Small Capital O?

Comment: This looks like it's probably just Android. That character is missing in the web browser too on my Android device, which means it's missing from the font that Android uses.

Comment: @animuson: Interesting, that is and isn't surprising to me. I guess Stack Exchange is off the hook. Thanks!

Comment: Repo (sortove) on iOS. Listing the characters one by one in the question, I see a "c", a box, an "r" and a "y". However, your display name, I see "Cory", but with what I believe is a replacement character (a plain "o") (i.e. The "r" and "y" are small caps, but the "o" looks like the plain ASCII "o")

Comment: @ColeJohnson At least iOS actually tells you there's an unknown character with a box rather than just *not displaying it*. ;)

Comment: @animuson Isn't that what a text renderer is _supposed to do_?

Comment: And yes, that's not the "O" letter. It's "Unicode Character 'LATIN LETTER SMALL CAPITAL O' (U+1D0F)" (and same for the "R" and "Y", only your "C" is a real English letter :))